# Sqlite throws NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, android, sql, android-asynctask, sqlite

From this code a Null exception is throw and I'm pusled as to why that is. The line that throws the NullReferenceException is this one,

```
if (await dbConn.FindAsync<ShoppingList>(x => x.Name == insertedList.Name) != null)
```

Here is the whole method:

```
public async Task<string> SaveSingleShoppingList(IShoppingList shoppingList)
{
    try 
    {
        var dbConn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);

        ShoppingList insertedList = (ShoppingList)shoppingList;

        await SaveGroceries(shoppingList.Groceries, shoppingList.Name, dbConn);

        if(await dbConn.FindAsync<ShoppingList>(x => x.Name == insertedList.Name) != null)
                await dbConn.UpdateAsync(insertedList);
        else
            await dbConn.InsertAsync(insertedList);

        return "Shopping list Saved!";
    } 
    catch (SQLiteException ex) 
    {
            return ex.Message;
    }
    catch(NullReferenceException nre) 
    {
        return nre.Message;
    }

}
```

**Below is the full extent of the exception message**

> {System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object   at
>   SQLite.TableQuery`1[ShoppingAssistant.ShoppingList].CompileExpr
>   (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr,
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1 queryArgs) [0x00000] in :0
>
> at SQLite.TableQuery`1[ShoppingAssistant.ShoppingList].CompileExpr
>   (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr,
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1 queryArgs) [0x00000] in :0
>
> at
>   SQLite.TableQuery`1[ShoppingAssistant.ShoppingList].GenerateCommand
>   (System.String selectionList) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    at
>   SQLite.TableQuery`1[ShoppingAssistant.ShoppingList].GetEnumerator ()
>   [0x00000] in :0
>
> at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ShoppingAssistant.ShoppingList].AddEnumerable
>   (IEnumerable`1 enumerable) [0x00000] in :0
>
> at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ShoppingAssistant.ShoppingList]..ctor
>   (IEnumerable`1 collection) [0x00000] in :0
>
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[ShoppingList] (IEnumerable`1
>   source) [0x00000] in :0
>
> at
>   SQLite.TableQuery`1[ShoppingAssistant.ShoppingList].FirstOrDefault ()
>   [0x00000] in :0
>
> at SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Find[ShoppingList]
>   (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1 predicate) [0x00000] in
>   :0
>
> at
>   SQLite.SQLiteAsyncConnection+c__AnonStorey7`1[ShoppingAssistant.ShoppingList].<>m__0
>   () [0x00000] in :0
>
> at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskActionInvoker+FuncInvoke`1[ShoppingAssistant.ShoppingList].Invoke
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task owner, System.Object state,
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task context) [0x00000] in :0
>
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke () [0x00000] in :0    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThreadStart () [0x00000]
>   in :0
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[ShoppingAssistant.ShoppingList].GetResult
>   () [0x00000] in :0    at
>   ShoppingAssistant.SQLiteDataAcces+d__2d.MoveNext
>   () [0x0009d] in
>   c:\Users\kaj\Desktop\dbTest\dbTest\SQLiteDataAcces.cs:187
>   } System.NullReferenceException

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that an object reference is `null`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: It has been fixed, It turned out that sqlite wants the objects that are inserted into the db not instantiated in a non empty constructor, as i turned out the string Name is set there so it was null when running the code, thanks for the suggestions. How do i upvote you guys?

Comment: my issue was that the DataContext was not added in the default constructor and therefore will always be null.